# Why is there a lexical error: invalid char in json text when json_string is sent over curl, but not in R console?

Tags: r, json, curl, plumber

I used Plumber (https://github.com/trestletech/plumber) to create a web API for a R source code, which purpose is to process a json_string as an input, and converting it into a R dataframe.

R code:

```
#* @param data
#* @post /predict
jsonToDF <- function(data) {
    library(jsonlite)
    dat <- fromJSON(data)
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I'm using the library `jsonlite` and the `fromJSON()` method.

Then I exposed the service locally via:

```
library(plumber) 
r <- plumb("code.R")
r$run(port=54321)
```

I used the curl request:

```
curl -v -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "testData='{\"a\":\"b\"}'" http://localhost:54321/predict
```

to send a json_string (`{"a":"b"}`) but this is the error i got:

```
<simpleError: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       '{"a":"b"}'
                     (right here) ------^
```

I used R console to double check the validity of the input, and i did not get the same error message.

```
> z <- fromJSON('{"a":"b"}')
> z
$a
[1] "b"
```

Can anyone explain to me why it works in R console, but not as an input in the data field of the curl requests? Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, add your R code, error message and Console output as **text**. remember that once added you can format it adding 4 spaces before each line or pressing Control+K

Comment: @Julio I've made the necessary changes, thanks for your suggestions. I hope the issue is clearer now.

Comment: Why do you have the `testData=` part in your data? That name doesn't seem to be referenced anywhere.

Comment: @MrFlick ah thanks for pointing that out, that was just an oversight on my part while copying over code during the process of crafting this question

Answer (score 3):

I managed to get the desired input by changing `"data='{\"a\":\"b\"}'"` to `"data={\"a\":\"b\"}"`. I simply removed the single quotation marks from the --data field of the curl command.

I think R automatically treats `{\"a\":\"b\"}` as a string after receiving it from curl, so there was no need for me to explicitly declare it as `'{\"a\":\"b\"}'` when sending it over curl.